# Identifying a previously marked object in a SceneKit scene

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

Here is a scene kit project of a 3 x 5 grid of spheres. You can move a blue sphere by tapping on it and then tapping an orange sphere, it will move to that location. Problem is I  don't know how to identify the sphere tapped to be marked for movement. I can only mark Blue1 or Blue 2 as the movable sphere. Here is iOS simulator and the composition of the .dae file. Consider the orange spheres as the empty spaces.[image]

Also, here is the code:

```
import SceneKit

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

enum Type { case Orange;  case Blue }
struct BoardLoc { var x: Int;   var y: Int }
var selectedLoc: BoardLoc?
var board: Array<Array<Type>> = []

override func viewDidLoad() { super.viewDidLoad()

    // add a scene
    let scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/balls10.dae")
    let scnView = view as SCNView
    scnView.scene = scene
    scnView.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true

    // add a tapper
    let gestures = NSMutableArray()
    let tapper = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleTap:")
    gestures.addObject(tapper)
    scnView.gestureRecognizers = gestures

    // add a 3 by 5 array, a board with most spaces empty except for 2 places
    for x in 0...2 {
        board.append(Array(count:5, repeatedValue:Type.Orange))
        for y in 0...4 {
            if x == 2 && y == 0 || x == 2 && y == 3 {
                board[x][y] = Type.Blue
            }
            else {
                board[x][y] = Type.Orange
            }
        }
    }
}

// handle tap
func handleTap(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    let scnView = view as SCNView
    let point = gesture.locationInView(scnView)
    if let hitResults = scnView.hitTest(point, options: nil) {
        if hitResults.count > 0 {
            let result: AnyObject! = hitResults[0]
            let tapLoc = BoardLoc(x: Int(point.x) / 106, y: Int(point.y) / 113)

            // if tapLoc blue, selectedLoc set as tapLoc
            if board[tapLoc.x][tapLoc.y] == Type.Blue {
                selectedLoc = tapLoc
            }

            // if tapLoc orange and selectedLoc not nil
            if board[tapLoc.x][tapLoc.y] == Type.Orange && selectedLoc != nil {

                // here is where I fail by just marking Blue1 for movement
                let ball = scnView.scene!.rootNode.childNodeWithName("Blue1", recursively: true)

                // placement of ball according to 3 by 5 grid
                let locX = Float(tapLoc.x) * 16.4 + 0.75
                let locY = Float(tapLoc.y) * -16.4 - 1.25

                let moveToTapLoc = SCNAction.moveTo(SCNVector3(x: locX, y: locY, z: 5), duration: 0.01)
                ball!.runAction(moveToTapLoc)

                // update array
                board[tapLoc.x][tapLoc.y] = Type.Blue
                board[selectedLoc!.x][selectedLoc!.y] = Type.Orange

                // set selectedLoc back to nil
                selectedLoc = nil
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

How do I mark the sphere tapped to be moved?

I have tried :

```
            if board[tapLoc.x][tapLoc.y] == Type.Blue {
                selectedLoc = tapLoc
                var ball = !result.node!.name!.hasPrefix("Blue")
            }

            // if tapLoc orange and selectedLoc not nil
            if board[tapLoc.x][tapLoc.y] == Type.Orange && selectedLoc != nil {


                // placement of ball according to 3 by 5 grid
                let locX = Float(tapLoc.x) * 16.4 + 0.75
                let locY = Float(tapLoc.y) * -16.4 - 1.25

                let moveToTapLoc = SCNAction.moveTo(SCNVector3(x: locX, y: locY, z: 5), duration: 0.01)
                ball!.runAction(moveToTapLoc)

                // update array
                board[tapLoc.x][tapLoc.y] = Type.Blue
                board[selectedLoc!.x][selectedLoc!.y] = Type.Orange

                // set selectedLoc back to nil
                selectedLoc = nil
            }
```

When ball!.runAction error occurs: Use of unresolved identifier 'ball'

Maybe add a variable before viewDidLoad used for the ball marked for movement but I don't know what type or how to label the variable.

Answer (score 0):

So one way to do it is to change selectedLoc to selectedLocBlue1 and add a similar variable, selectedLocBlue2.  Then, instead of 2 if statements in the handleTap function, use 4 if statements, 2 for selectedLocBlue1 and 2 for selectedLocBlue2.  Also change the array to reflect that there are 2 different types of blue and change enum have 3 types, Orange, Blue1, Blue2.  This I'm sure is a backwards way of doing it so please critique. Thanks.